# Active Record 3.0 and Castle.Core 3.0

Tags: c#, .net, castle-windsor, castle-activerecord

Does anyone knows when there will be an official build for Castle Active Record that would link to Castle.Core 3.0? With current official builds it's not possible to use both Active Record and Windsor - the first looking for 2.5.1 of the Castle.Core and the second for 3.0.

Does anyone use such combo?

Basically: Is Active Record alive? Should we expect anything to come any time soon or is this project abandoned?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this doesn't come out as rude, but there seems to be a misunderstanding here about how open source works. With most open source projects, you don't get to "expect anything to come any time soon". Doing so basically means expecting other people to work for you for free. A project is not dead because it hasn't yet updated some dependency to its latest version (which was released about 1.5 months ago). If that were the case, most projects would be dead! :)

Some relevant metrics to measure project liveliness include (with links to ActiveRecord):

- [Github watchers, forks, page views](https://github.com/castleproject/ActiveRecord/graphs/traffic).
- [Download stats](http://sourceforge.net/projects/castleproject/files/ActiveRecord/stats/timeline?dates=2009-01-24+to+2012-01-30)
- Volume and frequency of questions and ratio of answers in the [mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/castle-project-users).
- [Volume and frequency of questions and ratio of answers on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/castle-activerecord).

As you can see, ActiveRecord use may be in decline but it's not dead at all.

So, to quote the [Castle website](http://www.castleproject.org/castle/projects.html): "We are driven by community involvement and welcome you to help out."

I encourage you to [fork the repository](https://github.com/castleproject/ActiveRecord) and try to update Core. If you run into any breaking changes you don't understand you can always rely on the [Castle dev list](http://groups.google.com/group/castle-project-devel).

Comment: I really regret using such form of expression. I know how open source works and I have a lot of respect and gratitude for what has been given to people for free. I am thankful for Castle project and didn't meant to be rude at all. It was meant to be a simple question to make you or Kozmic answer (or any other user that simply got through the problem of using this combo together). As for updating Core - I think it's a matter of updating Active Record so it will use latest Core. Am I right?

Comment: @IAmDeveloper : no problem! yes, it's just a matter of updating Core in ActiveRecord, compiling, running the tests, and fixing any things that may break. Give it a try and let us know if you run into any difficulties!

Comment: I made a try - compiling went smoothly, but not tests. I don't have time now to check if tests also failed for the old Castle.Core , but will try to do it next week.